# Polybutylene (PB) male to compression female shut-off valve?

Tags: plumbing, sink, shutoff

I am replacing my bathroom sink, which has polybutylene piping. New sink has compression fittings. **Does anyone know if there are places that sell polybutylene-compression shutoff valves?** Or do I have to buy a PB-PEX adaptor, then a PEX-compression shutoff?

Saw a 1/2 push/fit to 3/8 compression shutoff valve, but it appears to be for PEX. Also found some PB/PB shutoffs but they don't sell PB anymore.

I have a crimping tool so don't mind a few crimp rings.

Comment: I have a dahl 1/4 turn pb to 3/8 compression shutoff so they at least used to make them.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger there aren't any existing shutoffs under my sink, so what you said is good to know!